# Work on Principled BSDF shader?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

I lived under the assumption that the Principled BSDF shader would make many other shaders superfluous, only to find that it falls short as a glass shader. I just wonder whether there are any efforts in progress to improve the Principled BSDF shader?

Comment: Yes there are. There was a video presentation on upcoming developments for the BSDF shader at the Blender Conference recently which you should be able to see [here](https://video.blender.org/w/9qeF5FNFcayzGs814RFmAu). It's approaching an hour long. As far as I know you don't have to be a subscriber to watch it.

Comment: The same video is also available on Youtube: [The new Principled BSDF model in Cycles - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DQeP363Xmn4)